# CSS width percentage accuracy

Tags: html, css

Would `width: 33.3%` or `width: 33.3333333%` be less wide (accurate) than `width: calc(100% / 3);` (would equal to 33.33∞ <- infinite). In Math it does, but CSS..?

Comment: Why not just use [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid) with something like `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` and stop worrying about such calculations?

Comment: I think you will like this https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: @xufox No, there is a difference between the 2 layouts. If the intrinsic width of the elements is not the same, repeat(3, 1fr) will not make 3 equal sizes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, the `calc` is more accurate. If I have 3 columns filling the entire viewport with equal width, the `calc(100vw / 3)` always work in all browser, but `33.3333vw` sometimes leaves a single pixel line in between.

You might find more info here: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit